# Gather custom events from a React app with Google Analytics 4

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics-4

I'm using [react-ga4](https://github.com/PriceRunner/react-ga4) to send custom events to Google Analytics 4. **I can see the events in the real-time dashboard** and I can see an event with the made up name I'm using in the select of events when creating a custom event with the ui, but **I can't find my data in the events tab** or anywhere else outside the real-time section.

Is there something I should do on Google Analaytics and/or **where can I find the custom data I'm sending?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes 24 hours to appear on the events tab

Comment: Why can only see event params in the real-time panel and only event names in other places,  i use react-ga4 pkg, eg . reactga4.event('name', { a: 123 } ) i can't find { a: 123 } in events tab

Answer (score -1):

You can also confirm the correctness of your code by checking the event's hit from the networks tab in the dev console of your browser.
The API to GA for your event should start with `https://analytics.google.com/g/collect?v...`. In the payload tab here, you should be able to view the following fields for your event:

- ep.category
- ep.action
- ep.label

NOTE: It takes upto 24hrs (as mentioned in above answer) for the event to appear in the events section of your GA4 property